# How can i replace a certain element in a list with an element from another list according to a condition

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to build a function that updates part of a list according to a condition.

here is an example of what I want:

```py
List1=[1,2,3,4,10,5,9,3,4]
List2=[2,4,6,8]
```

I want to update `List1` to be `[2,4,6,8,10,5,9,6,8]`, and here is my code to do that:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 9, 3, 4]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8]


def update_signal(gain):
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            if x[j] == y[i] / gain:
                x[j] = y[i]
            elif x[j - 1] == y[i] / gain:
                break


update_signal(2)  # for this example only gain =2
print("x=", x)
print("y=", y)
```

the expected output is:

```py
x=[2,4,6,8,10,5,9,6,8] 
y=[2,4,6,8]
```

what it actually prints is:

```py
x= [8, 8, 6, 8, 10, 5, 9, 6, 8]
y= [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

so, what am I doing wrong to make this function behave like this?

Comment: "according to a condition" -- what is the condition?

Comment: You're processing `x` multiple times. So after you replace an element, you'll consider the new element when checking the condition against a different element of `y`.

Comment: Maybe you should change the order of the loops, and make `x` the outer loop.

Comment: And break out of the inner loop whenever you perform a replacement.

Comment: Can you explain the expected logic(condition) in sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def update_signal(gain):
    return [item * gain if item * gain in y else item for item in x]
```

Comment: It may different if `y`'s elements are not divided by gain. For example, `y = [1, 3, 5]` and `gain = 2`.

Comment: This is maybe not OP expected.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your algorithm means:

- let `i` is `x`'s arbitrary element.
- let `j` is `y`'s arbitrary element.
- if `i` is same with `j / gain`, replace `i` to `j`

(If I am wrong, point it please. Then I'll fix for it.)

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 9, 3, 4]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8]


def update_signal(gain):
    convert_table = {i / gain: i for i in y}
    x[:] = [convert_table.get(i, i) for i in x]


update_signal(2)  # for this example only gain =2
print('x = ', x)
print('y = ', y)
```

output:

```py
x =  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 5, 9, 6, 8]
y =  [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 9, 3, 4]
x_copy = x[:]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8]

def update_signal(gain):
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        cond = y[i] / gain
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            if x[j] == cond:
                x_copy[j] = y[i]
            elif x[j - 1] == cond:
                continue


update_signal(2)  # for this example only gain =2
print("x=", x_copy)
print("y=", y)
```

Comment: Your continue statement isn't needed since it's the last line of code in the loop anyway ;-) it looks like this one works though @Marcus

Comment: @Todd Yes, you're right. But since I still don't understand what the asker means of the condition judgment `elif x[j - 1] == cond:`, I keep it in my answer.

Comment: The results are the same whether to declare `globla` or not. `list` is global variable in Python. So there is no need to declare `global x_copy` here since `x_copy` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

```py
x=[1,2,3,4,10,5,9,3,4]
y=[2,4,6,8]
```

```
def update_signal(gain):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if y[j]//x[i]==gain:
                x[i]=y[j]
                break
```